# What is the difference between Pyrus and Composer?

Tags: zend-framework2, composer-php, pyrus

I'm new to Zend Framework 2.0, after reading the documentation I know that we can install Zend via some package managers as Pyrus, Composer. But I don't know which package manager should I choose? Please explain to me some differences between them, thank you for help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Pyrus is basically [PEAR2](http://pear2.php.net/), and needs the end developer of a package to configure a pyrus distribution channel to make packages public.

Composer is backed by the main [packagist.org](http://packagist.org/) repository, with the availability of own channels through [satis](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md) if necessary.

Pyrus is mantained, but has not much [activity](https://github.com/pyrus/Pyrus/graphs/commit-activity) on its main repository, composer is [much more active](https://github.com/composer/composer/graphs/commit-activity).

[Composer](http://getcomposer.org/) is the most used package manager for PHP currently available. Most ZF2 modules currently support it and don't support Pyrus, so I strongly suggest you to get used to it.

Related: [ZF2 + doctrine without composer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979381/zf2-doctrine-without-composer) (an example of how this tool is becoming necessary).

Comment: +1 for example of how crucial composer is becoming to some framework workflows.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Ocramius' explanation:

- Pyrus is **not** PEAR2. Pyrus is a standalone tool that can install packages from any [PEAR-compatible channel](http://pear.php.net/channels/), *including* pear.php.net and pear2.php.net.
- Pyrus is able to install and compile [PECL packages](http://pecl.php.net/) (PHP extensions).
- Publishing a package yourself is easier with composer. You only need one single file in your git repository; Composer can install directly from there. Pyrus on the other hand needs a bunch of XML files you can't hand-generate - so you have to use a channel server software like [Pirum](http://www.pirum-project.org/).