# ZF2 private repository for project

Tags: php, git, repository, zend-framework2, bitbucket

I started ZendSkeletonApplication via Composer. I will need for my project PRIVATE repository (Git). How to do it? Skeleton have now .git files so how I can work with my project for example on BitBucket?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to create a ZF2 skeleton project from scratch is to use ZFTool (http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.1/en/modules/zendtool.introduction.html). Install it to /usr/local/bin (with executable permissions) and then you can do this:

```
$ zftool.phar create project project_name
```

This will give you a skeleton application in the project_name folder which is completely git free.

Now create a private repository on BitBucket and follow the instructions for setting up with code already on your disk.

Note that the project created in project_name has a .gitmodules file. If you're using Composer, you can just delete this file before you add to BitBucket. If you want to use submodules, then its set up with ZF2 as a submodule ready for you to init and update.

Comment: Thanks for answer. It's best way I think but I probably have no choice and must composer to install other components like doctrine etc;/ But what happends if I delete this modules file? Everythink from vendor will be scanned by git and I have to commit it to bucket? Secound thing I don't like this mess whats doing Composer (clean project via Composer 150mb).

Comment: The skeleton app provides two ways to handle dependencies: Git sub modules via the .gitmodules file (http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) and Composer via the composer.json file (http://www.getcomposer.org). You probably only want to use one or the other in any given project.

Answer (score 0):

By utilizing the submodule feature of git, you may have your own project on bitbucket and have the zend library, etc. as a submodule in the seperate lib/-directory, like so:

```
YourProject/   <-- Your git working tree (via git init)
  public/
  libs/
    Zend/      <-- a git submodule
  application/
```

The command to add a submodule is `git submodule add http://zf-repo libs/Zend`. You can then seperately update and track the zend framework, because your main git working tree will also reference a specific version of the Zend Framework Library.

Comment: I have now .git folder in MyProject dir so I have to delete .git folder manually and git init new repository? My main git repo what I want place on BB should ignore vendor/ZF2 folder where is now ZF2 library as git submodule but shoulnt ignore vendor/MyZendExtension lib folder.

Answer (score 0):

Once you forked the [ZendSkeletonApplication](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendSkeletonApplication), you can push the fork to a private repository in your Bitbucket account or on your own servers/network.

You can deploy your own packages/modules on Bitbucket and even [require them via composer](http://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/handling-private-packages-with-satis.md) if you want, but as @Lars stated, it's possible to simply use a [git submodule](http://book.git-scm.com/5_submodules.html) if that's easier for you.

There's also a great presentation by Niels Aderman about [advanced composer usage](http://www.naderman.de/slippy/src/?file=2012-11-22-You-Thought-Composer-Couldnt-Do-That.html) if you're not familiar with the tool.

Comment: I have now clean local copy of ZendSkeletonApplication installed via Composer and I don't know what to do now.. I have to delete this .git folder what exists now from cloning?

Comment: @JokerDark2 no, that's the git repo metadata. If you are not familiar with git and prefer to use SVN or another version control system, you can delete it: I personally don't suggest it.

Comment: I just want git on bitbucket. I want have possibility to add later doctrine or other components not only ZF2(without composer). My main repo should allow me to work localy with eveythink what I develop or add to my application or vendor. I installed now ZF2 skeleton without Composer (via Git submodules). So now I need only to import files from my computer to BitBucket account and it will work fine?

Comment: I'm trying now to import my copy like BitBucket expects it but after: git remote add origin ... I'm getting fatal error: remote origin already exists..

Comment: Adding doctrine to a zf2 project without composer is problematic: see my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14979381/zf2-doctrine-without-composer . Bitbucket makes no difference if you use composer or submodules.

Comment: `git remote add bitbucket <your-repo-url> && git push -u bitbucket --all` will do

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! Now its working fine on bitbucket ;) later I try to add somethink via Composer.